Wordpress returns empty page
The WP site returns an empty page.
https://webscraping.pro/wp-admin returns the same blank page.
Why is that ? How to fix it ?
Server (linux, Centos 7) reload did not work.

Update 1
The hosting support has suggested:

The vesta control panel is installed on your server. You can log in to the control panel at https://178.208.88.6:8083/login.
In PHP settings you can enable error output or check the site error log.

Log error file

https://pastebin.com/ULQUfJVm
https://pastebin.com/X3Tuv9J4
https://pastebin.com/NAGt4JpN

Update 2
When I've entered to the WP public_html folder I've found the following:
[root@webscraping public_html]# ls -l
total 420
drwxr-xr-x   2 admin  admin   4096 May 24 11:03 3258191a
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root   57721 Sep 30  2021 composer-installer.php__d28417e
-rw-r--r--   1 admin  admin  45318 May 22 09:40 hemianopia.php__d28417e
-rw-r--r--   1 admin  admin   2704 May 24 03:50 index.php
-rw-r--r--   1 admin  admin   2704 May 24 03:50 index.php__d28417e
-rw-r--r--   1 admin  admin     20 Apr 29  2022 i.php__d28417e
-rw-r--r--   1 admin  admin  45318 May 22 07:03 kebbucks.php__d28417e
-rw-r--r--.  1 admin  admin  19915 Jul 28  2022 license.txt__d28417e
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root       0 Jun  7 16:40 ls
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root    4096 Nov  1  2020 node__d28417e
-rw-r--r--.  1 admin  admin   7401 Jul 28  2022 readme.html__d28417e
-rw-r--r--   1 admin  admin   1710 May 22 11:12 robots.txt__d28417e
drwxrwxrwx   3 root   root    4096 May 25 04:21 scraperservice2__d28417e
drwxr-xr-x.  8 apache apache  4096 Feb  3  2021 src__d28417e
drw-r--r--. 14 admin  admin   4096 Sep  4  2020 studyportals__d28417e
-rw-r--r--   1 admin  admin      1 May 22 10:52 uxo.txt__d28417e
-rw-r--r--.  1 admin  admin   7165 Jul 28  2022 wp-activate.php__d28417e
-rw-r--r--   1 admin  admin   7062 May 22 09:40 wp-add.php__d28417e
drw-r--r--.  9 admin  admin   4096 Jul 28  2022 wp-admin__d28417e
-rw-r--r--.  1 admin  admin    351 Aug 20  2020 wp-blog-header.php__d28417e
-rw-r--r--.  1 admin  admin   2338 Jul 28  2022 wp-comments-post.php__d28417e
-rw-r--r--   1 admin  admin   2911 Oct  7  2021 wp-config.php__d28417e
-rw-r--r--.  1 admin  admin   3001 Jul 28  2022 wp-config-sample.php__d28417e
drw-r--r--.  6 admin  admin   4096 May 23 12:03 wp-content__d28417e
-rw-r--r--.  1 admin  admin   3943 Jul 28  2022 wp-cron.php__d28417e
drw-r--r--. 26 admin  admin  16384 Jul 28  2022 wp-includes__d28417e
-rw-r--r--.  1 admin  admin   2494 Jul 28  2022 wp-links-opml.php__d28417e
-rw-r--r--.  1 admin  admin   3973 Jul 28  2022 wp-load.php__d28417e
-rw-r--r--.  1 admin  admin  48498 Jul 28  2022 wp-login.php__d28417e
-rw-r--r--.  1 admin  admin   8577 Jul 28  2022 wp-mail.php__d28417e
-rw-r--r--.  1 admin  admin  23706 Jul 28  2022 wp-settings.php__d28417e
-rw-r--r--.  1 admin  admin  32051 Jul 28  2022 wp-signup.php__d28417e
-rw-r--r--.  1 admin  admin   4748 Jul 28  2022 wp-trackback.php__d28417e
-rw-r--r--.  1 admin  admin   3236 Aug 20  2020 xmlrpc.php__d28417e


What is the strange suffix __d28417e ? Should I rename files to remove it from the files ?
What are the files created in the May of this year right before the site malfunction ?

Update 3
I've entered VestaCP yet I do not know if this somehow can help:

Update 4
I've renamed to wp_content but again I've failed to log-in:
-rw-r--r--   1 admin  admin   2911 Oct  7  2021 wp-config.php__d28417e
-rw-r--r--.  1 admin  admin   3001 Jul 28  2022 wp-config-sample.php__d28417e
drw-r--r--.  6 admin  admin   4096 May 23 12:03 wp-content
-rw-r--r--.  1 admin  admin   3943 Jul 28  2022 wp-cron.php__d28417e
drw-r--r--. 26 admin  admin  16384 Jul 28  2022 wp-includes__d28417e
-rw-r--r--.  1 admin  admin   2494 Jul 28  2022 wp-links-opml.php__d28417e
-rw-r--r--.  1 admin  admin   3973 Jul 28  2022 wp-load.php__d28417e
-rw-r--r--.  1 admin  admin  48498 Jul 28  2022 wp-login.php__d28417e
-rw-r--r--.  1 admin  admin   8577 Jul 28  2022 wp-mail.php__d28417e
-rw-r--r--.  1 admin  admin  23706 Jul 28  2022 wp-settings.php__d28417e
-rw-r--r--.  1 admin  admin  32051 Jul 28  2022 wp-signup.php__d28417e
-rw-r--r--.  1 admin  admin   4748 Jul 28  2022 wp-trackback.php__d28417e
-rw-r--r--.  1 admin  admin   3236 Aug 20  2020 xmlrpc.php__d28417e
[root@webscraping public_html]# cd wp-content
[root@webscraping wp-content]# ls
index.php  tablepress-combined.min.css  tablepress-custom.min.css  upgrade
plugins    tablepress-custom.css        themes                     uploads
[root@webscraping wp-content]# cd themes
[root@webscraping themes]# ls -l
total 24
-rw-r--r--. 1 admin admin   28 Aug 20  2020 index.php
drwxr-xr-x. 8 admin admin 4096 Aug 20  2020 twentynineteen
drwxr-xr-x. 5 admin admin 4096 Aug 20  2020 twentyseventeen
drwxr-xr-x. 7 admin admin 4096 Oct 12  2021 twentytwenty
drwxr-xr-x  6 admin admin 4096 Dec 16  2020 twentytwentyone
drwxr-xr-x  7 admin admin 4096 Jul 28  2022 twentytwentytwo
[root@webscraping themes]# wp-content

but strange that the wp_content folder was created at May 23 of this year: "4096 May 23 12:03 "

If this is your site, check your error logs or contact your hosting support team.

If you posted the contents of the error log we might be able to help you. We can do absolutely nothing with the fact that your host has told you to check it.

@ChrisCox, I've added error logs for the main domain. There are also some of subdomains. Should i put them public too?

I'd refer to @eny's answer below.

See my findings in the Update 2.

the site seems to be infected by malware:
https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/results/https/webscraping.pro
which could explain the issues you have; these guides should help you deal with malware removal:
https://wordpress.org/support/article/faq-my-site-was-hacked/
https://sucuri.net/guides/how-to-clean-hacked-wordpress/

thanks. See my findings in the Update 2. Any further help/tips?

I have checked the Error log and found the following Fatal Error
 PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_header() in /home/admin/web/webscraping.pro/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentytwenty/404.php:10\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /home/admin/web/webscraping.pro/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentytwenty/404.php on line 10

So seems the theme is causing the issue and @eny might be right that your site is infected with Malware.
You can try to rename the theme twentytwenty in the following path and see if after that it allows you to log in or not.
Path:
public_html > wp-content > themes
If you are able to access WP admin after that, you can install Malware Scanner and removal plugin like WordFence and make sure website is clean.

"rename the theme twentytwenty " -> rename to what name, any arbitrary name?

see my Update 4.

Seems like there is some kind of malware script running on your website which is creating folders or file.
To further check it and find the root issue server & websites needs to be checked.
